# Why does this code require casting?

Tags: java, generics, casting, linked-list, variadic-functions

I'm studying generics right now, and to my understanding, we use generics so we can avoid/remove the need to cast, so why do I have to cast when adding the item and the linkedlist?

```
public class ThisIsCode<E> implements Code{

    LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<>();

    public final void add(E... item) {
        List<E> thingie = new LinkedList<>();

        for (E i: item) {
            thingie.add((E) item);
        }

        list.add((E)thingie); 

    }
```

I also have to cast in this method as well, and in an array?? I don't think I should be putting the item into an array, so I'm a bit confused.

```
public void addSingle(Object item) {
    add((E[]) item);

}
```

Comment: Then again, why not replace the whole method with `list.addAll(Arrays.asList(items))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a *cast*, you are adding the wrong thing. This

```
for (E i: item) {
    thingie.add((E) item);
}
```

should be

```
for (E i: item) {
    thingie.add(i);
}
```

and

```
list.add((E)thingie);
```

should be something like

```
list.addAll(thingie);
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much! The varargs is really new to me.
What is the difference between list.add() and list.addAll()?

Comment: [`List.addAll(Collection<? extends E>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) adds every item from the `Collection` to the `list`; [`List.add(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) is to add one element of type `E` to the `list`.

Comment: Is there anything I can do about the add((E[]) item);?

Answer (score 1):

> we use generics so we can avoid/remove the need to cast

That's not 100% true, we use generics for [type safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). The lack of need
for casting is just one of the many benefits that generics bring to the table.

---

The reason you're needing to cast your objects in your
foreach loop is because you're adding the `item` list itself
to your linked list in each iteration of the loop. What you
should be doing is adding the elements of the array.

This is what you meant to do:

```
for (E i: item) {
    thingie.add(i);
}
```

The reason you need to cast your objects again in this line: `list.add((E)thingie);`,
is because your adding a linked list to a linked list - not the elements
of the lists. What you should be doing here is iterating over all the elements
and adding them one by one; or use one of java's built in methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your code already says that

> for each E in item

. So item is expected to return an `E` Object. Also, Im not sure. But the code :

```
for (E i: item) {
    thingie.add((E) item);
}
```

is supossed to be

```
for (E i: item) {
    thingie.add(i);
}
```

It is a list of `E`. Based on the 3rd line. Not a list  of an array of `E`.Hope it gives some clarification.